# Google Apps Script: weird page layout in a script formatted document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm working on a script that applies custom headings to a plain text document imported in Google Docs. The scripts works pretty much as it should. However the resulting document has a weird layout, as if random page breaks were inserted here and there. But there are no page breaks and I can't understand the reason of this layout. Checking the paragraph attributes give me no hints on what is wrong.

Here is the text BEFORE the script is applied:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MzFvlkG13i3rrUcz5jmmSppG4sBH6zTXr7RViwdqaIo/edit?usp=sharing

You can make a copy of the document and execute the script (from the Scripts menu, choose Apply Headings). The script applies the appropriate heading to the scene heading, name of the character, dialogue, etc.

As you can see, at the bottom of page 2 and 3 of the resulting document there is a big gap  and I can't figure out why. The paragraph attributes seem ok to me...

Here is a copy of the script:

```
// Apply headings to sceneheadings, actions, characters, dialogues, parentheticals 
// to an imported plain text film script;

function ApplyHeadings() {
  var pars = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs(); 
  for(var i=0; i<pars.length; i++) {
    var par = pars[i];
    var partext = par.getText();
    var indt = par.getIndentStart();
    Logger.log(indt);
    if (indt > 100 && indt < 120) {
      var INT = par.findText("INT.");
      var EXT = par.findText("EXT.");
      if (INT != null || EXT != null) {
        par.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
        par.setAttributes(ResetAttributes());
      }
      else {
        par.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL);
        par.setAttributes(ResetAttributes());
      }
    }
    else if (indt > 245 && indt < 260) {
      par.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);
      par.setAttributes(ResetAttributes());
    }
    else if (indt > 170 && indt < 190) {
      par.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3);
      par.setAttributes(ResetAttributes());
    }
    else if (indt > 200 && indt < 240) {
      par.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING4);
      par.setAttributes(ResetAttributes());       
    }
  }
}

// Reset all the attributes to "null" apart from HEADING;
function ResetAttributes() {
  var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.STRIKETHROUGH] = null;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = null;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.INDENT_START] = null;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.INDENT_END] = null;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.INDENT_FIRST_LINE] = null;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = null;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.ITALIC] = null;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = null;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = null;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = null;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_BEFORE] = null;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_AFTER] = null;
  return style;
}
```

A couple of screenshots to make the problem more clear.

This is page 2 of the document BEFORE the script is applied.

[image: Page 2 before script]

This is page two AFTER the script is applied. Headings are applied correctly but... Why the white space at the bottom?

[image]

Note: if you manually re-apply HEADING2 to the first paragraph of page 3 (AUDIO TV), the paragraph will jump back to fill the space at the bottom of page 2. This action, however, doesn't change any attribute in the paragraph. So why the magic happens?

Thanks a lot for your patience.

Comment: without seing your text source nor your code what could we say ?

Comment: Thank, now this is clear as  a clear sky :-)

Comment: I just edited my question, I tried to give all the needed infos without giving too much... Hope it's better...

Comment: Thanks for this script, That's a brilliant idea and I'll make use of it for sure. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

That was an interesting problem ;-)

I copied your doc, ran the script and had a surprise  : nothing happened !

It took me a few minutes to realize that the copy I just made had no style defined for headings, everything was for some reason in courrier new 12pt, including the headings.

I examined the log and saw the indent values, played with that a lot to finally see that the headings were there but not changing the style.

So I went in the doc menu and set 'Use my default style and... everything looks fine, see screen capture below.
[image]

So now your question : it appears that there must be something wrong in your style definition, by "wrong" I mean something that changes more than just the font Style and size but honestly I can't see any way to guess what since I'm unable to reproduce it... Please try resetting your heading styles and re-define your default.... and tell us what happens then.

PS : here are my default heading styles : (and the url of my copy in view only :https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yP0RRCrRSsQc9zCk-sdfu5olNGDkoIrabXanII4qUG0/edit?usp=sharing )

[image]

Comment: As strange as it seems, the styles for a "Film Script" are all Courier New 12! The visual appeareance of the text is not suppose to change after the script is executed. The aim of the script is to apply a different headings for the scene heading, the name of the character, the dialogues, the action description, etc. so that the "film script" can be easily edited by the screenwriter (otherwise he would soon mess up the document with different spacing and indents). I'll to make my problem with a few screenshots...

Comment: I see... In my opinion the result that I get with default heading style is not bad, easy to read and clear enough... but of course that's only an opinion and I'm not a screenplay writer :-) how in fact would you like it to look ? All in the same typeface?  Then your script does it pretty well but how does that improve readability?    PS: sorry, this is a bit out of subject for this site, I know :-)

Comment: Well, it's not my decision, this is how Hollywood decided to format film scripts many years ago and I cannot change it ;-) I added some screenshot to my question to make it more clear. Hope you are patient enough to follow me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I continued (not all this time, I admit) to play with your doc and I think it might be an issue with the margins... when I set the top & bottom margins to 0 or 0.2 I don't see any blank spaces anymore, otherwise it appears that the paragraphs behave as "blocks" that can't be separated across pages and that some of them are just near the limit of a page size.(I know this is not the explanation of the issue you have but I'm looking for a way around... One last question though : is the document going to stay with its headings in courrier new 12 pt ?

Comment: Yes, headings are going to stay in courier new 12, which is the industry standard. It might be a good idea to play around with margins, I can try setting them to 0 at the beginning and put them back in place at the end of the script. I'll let you know how it goes!  Still, I would like to understand the reason of this layout issue, if only to come up with an effective workaround...